# In Matlab how can I efficiently apply an operation with a 1D coefficient set to each colour of an image when stored in a 3D array using matrix math?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a large image in a 3D array with axes image[y,x,colour] I wish to apply the same operation using a 3 element array for the coefficients.

For example I am currently doing the following:

```
rgb(:,:,1) = (rgb(:,:,1) - kBlackOffset(1)) * gain(1);
rgb(:,:,2) = (rgb(:,:,2) - kBlackOffset(2)) * gain(2);
rgb(:,:,3) = (rgb(:,:,3) - kBlackOffset(3)) * gain(3);
```

It seems like I ought to be able to do this in a more efficient way in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply permute your offsets and gain to the 3rd dimensions.

Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
rgb = im2double(rgb);
gain = 1:3;
kBlackOffset = 1:3;
rgb = rgb - reshape(gain,[1 1 3]).*reshape(kBlackOffset,[1 1 3]);
```

If you're using an older version of MATLAB you may need to do this:

```
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
rgb = im2double(rgb);
gain = 1:3;
kBlackOffset = 1:3;
rgb = bsxfun(@minus,rgb,reshape(gain,[1 1 3]).*reshape(kBlackOffset,[1 1 3]));
```